# Use array_column in combination with preg_match

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mapreduce, preg-match, array-column

Lets suppose we have an array of arrays that needs to be converted to rows

From this:

```
Array
(
    [subject] => Array
        (
            [0] => EDN:LOC:DERR
            [1] => EDN:LOC:DOXX
            [2] => EDN:LOC:NTTT
            [3] => EDN:LOC:NAGA
        )

    [object] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABS:D01::ADFPAZ01
            [1] => ABS:D01::DOXYWITX
            [2] => ABS:D01::NAGBAAD2
            [3] => ABS:D01::NAGGAAD2
        )

    [units] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABS:D06::UNAA
            [1] => ABS:D06::UMMM
            [2] => ABS:D06::UPOP
            [3] => ABS:D06::UPOP
        )
```

To this:

```
[0] => "'DERR' , 'ADFPAZ01' , 'UNAA'"
[1] => "'DOXX' , 'DOXYWITX' , 'UMMM'"
[2] => "'NTTT' , 'NAGBAAD2' , 'UPOP'"
[3] => "'NAGA' , 'NAGGAAD2' , 'UPOP'"
```

So I need the arrays to be cleaned by a pattern and compressed into lines.

I managed the compact view with the following function

```
$array_res = array();

for ($i=0; $i<=$totalEntries-1; $i++) {
   array_push($array_res, implode("', '", array_column($array_of_arrays, $i)));
}
```

My regex pattern is `$pattern = '([^.:]*$)';` And it collects a sequence of letters from the end of the string until it finds a colon. And I used `preg_match($pattern, $string, $match)` to receive the proper string into the $match variable.

However, I cannot combine the above two procedures either with array_filter or array_map inside the for loop.

EDIT: Note that there can be a subarray that contains values without a colon. In that case we have to get the value as is

```
[units] => Array
    (
         [0] => NULL
         [1] => VALUE1
         [2] => VALUE2
         [3] => NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a regex, this just uses `array_walk()` to process the extracted column and for each item it uses `strrchr()` with `:` as the last character to match (although it will include the `:`, so uses `substr()` to remove the first char)...

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$totalEntries-1; $i++) {
    $newRow = array_column($array_of_arrays, $i);
    array_walk($newRow, function (&$data) { 
        $data = substr(strrchr(":".$data, ":") , 1);
    });
    $array_res[] = "'".implode("', '", $newRow)."'";
}
```

The part `":".$data` deals with the time when there is no `:` in the string, it will always ensure that it does find something to use.

Comment: This is an excellent solution! However I forgot to mention that in case there is a colon-less value, we want to get the value as is

Comment: I've updated the code, it just prepends `:` to ensure there is always one to find.

Comment: @Moreorem then you should have presented a better [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Other way:

```
$arr = [
    'subject' => [ 'EDN:LOC:DERR', 'EDN:LOC:DOXX', 'EDN:LOC:NTTT', 'EDN:LOC:NAGA' ],
    'object' => [ 'ABS:D01::ADFPAZ01', 'ABS:D01::DOXYWITX', 'ABS:D01::NAGBAAD2', 'ABS:D01::NAGGAAD2' ],
    'units' => [ 'ABS:D06::UNAA', 'ABS:D06::UMMM', 'ABS:D06::UPOP', 'ABS:D06::UPOP' ]
];

$res = [];
$fmt = "'%s', '%s', '%s'";

foreach ($arr['subject'] as $k => $v) {
    $res[] = vsprintf($fmt, preg_replace('~^.*:~', '', array_column($arr, $k)));
}

print_r($res);
```

Notice: If you don't know in advance your array length, nothing forbids to build the format pattern dynamically (using `str_repeat` or `implode`).